# Move Google Now screen in 4.4 (KitKat)

Tags: launcher, google-now, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

Is it possible to move the location of the new "Google Now Screen" in KitKat?

The screen is typically left of the home screen. What I want to achieve is, that it moves 1 screen further left, giving me another screen for apps/widgets left of the home screen.

Comment: No, but you should be able to add a screen and then move it to be next to the Google Now screen.

Comment: @AlEverett: The one downside to that, unfortunately, is that the leftmost screen is always "home" on Google's launcher. So if you had 3 pages of apps/widgets, you could not make the home button take you to the middle one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with the Google launcher, but it's fully possible in 4.4 in general, you just need to stop using Google's launcher. The "regular" launcher is still included so you can switch to that.

Comment: If OP wants to keep Google Now two screens to the left, however, this wouldn't be suitable for him. Or would it?

Comment: If that is his specific requirement it seems there is no way to do that currently, no.

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to have the Google Now screen as the left-most screen because it is largely occupied by cards that slide-out to the right. Would make scrolling further to a left screen complicated.

As an aside, careful with the fast right swipes to move across many screens. You might tend to slide out a card from the Now screen.
Nothing to worry though,

1. The Now screen is strikingly different from your usual screens
2. There is also an undo for a quick roll-back